# Windows 8.1 "PC Settings" is giving a Runtime Library Error on opening

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, runtime-error, visual-c++

I wanted to open PC settings on my Windows 8.1, and suddenly an error message popped up: it's a Visual C++ Runtime error.
PC settings successfully opened, but it made an error sound. So I went back to my desktop, and I saw a error message, it said something about terminating, but it didn't terminate it in any way.

Why does it happens, how to solve this problem?

[image: Here's a picture of it]!

Comment: Someone on [tomshardware suggested](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/runtime-error-in-computer-settings.2605183/) to _open an administrator command prompt and use `sfc /scannow`_.

Comment: BTW welcome on superuser... let me know if the answer below helps...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be <sup>[[1](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/runtime-error-in-computer-settings.2605183/),[2](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/microsoft-visual-c-runtime-library-runtime-error/5c931666-b8a0-4871-b34e-d1fe66e39368)]</sup> a corruption in the Microsoft Visual C++ redistributables components.

Some methods to restore the functionality are suggested  <sup>[[3](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-hardware/microsoft-c-runtime-error/8efa9cc8-c426-4b74-9ad3-50c9124dd4b8)]</sup>, based for example on

- Reinstall the Runtime components of Visual C++ Libraries (**I suggest to start from this one**)

  1. Uninstall any existing Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package

     > a. Open Programs and Features.
     >   b. From the list, find Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package and click on it.
     >   c. Right click on it and select Uninstall.
     >   d. Restart the computer.
  2. Install the latest Microsoft Visual C++

     > Visual Studio 2013: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng#downloads
- to perform a clean boot (method 1 of reference [[3](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-hardware/microsoft-c-runtime-error/8efa9cc8-c426-4b74-9ad3-50c9124dd4b8)]).

  > Clean boot will check if any third party application is causing the issue, as clean boot helps in eliminating software conflicts.
  >   How to troubleshoot problem by performing clean boot in Windows: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135
  >   Note: Once you are done with the troubleshooting, refer to the steps in “How to reset the computer to start as usual after troubleshooting with clean boot “to reset computer as usual.